# Snap.svg hiding and showing objects from different layers of existing svg file

Tags: snap.svg

I have defined variable 'circle' which is originally on hidden layer of svg. So basically I would like to know how to show and hide it again.

EDIT: Aright, I'm sorry I wasn't very specific. I'm a beginner :) I have .svg file with two circles - black and grey. I'd like the black button to appear when the grey one is hovered. The point is, I would like the circles to be on different layers and manage the visibility from Inkscape(hide all elements on given layer). Here's fragment the code of svg file which contains inkscape meta for "grey" layer:

```
<g
 inkscape:label="Grey"
 inkscape:groupmode="layer"
 id="layer1"
 transform="translate(-8.571418,-6.6478954)">
<path
   sodipodi:type="arc"
   style="fill:#a4a4a4;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
   id="grey"
   sodipodi:cx="180"
   sodipodi:cy="289.50504"
   sodipodi:rx="90"
   sodipodi:ry="90"
   d="m 270,289.50504 c 0,49.70562 -40.29437,90 -90,90 -49.70563,0 -90,-40.29438 -90,-90 0,-49.70563 40.29437,-90 90,-90 49.70563,0 90,40.29437 90,90 z"
   transform="translate(-67.142862,-184.28571)" />
```

And here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Button</title>

<script src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<script>

    window.onload = function () {

        var s = Snap("#iconDiv");

        Snap.load("button.svg", function(f) {

            grey = f.select("#grey");
            black = f.select("#black");

            grey.hover(function() {
                       black.animate({y:200}, 200, mina.elastic);

                    },

                    function() {
                        black.animate({y:180}, 200, mina.elastic);
                    }
            );

            s.append(f);
        });
    };
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="iconDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should post some code as to what you have tried.

Comment: Indeed. You haven't even said how its hidden.

Comment: Edited, thank you. The element is on the layer that is hidden. It is in the .svg file code but I don't know just how to reach it.

Comment: You haven't shown all of the svg, so its not 100% clear, but I would imagine you would just do something like select('#layer2').animate({opacity: 0 },1000) or whatever the layers id that you want to disappear. You may find in your code that you need to append the fragment before adding a click handler to it first, I'm not quite sure what the correct behaviour is when you add a handler to a fragment selection (it may be fine, but if nothing happens, I would look there). If you put it on a jsfiddle it will be easier to help further.